# HTML table: multiple rows for one data? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have multiple rows for one data set using HTML table.

```
var row = 0;

var test = [{
  food: "A",
  grade: ["1", "2", "3", "5"]
},
{
  food: "B",
  grade: ["1", "2"]
},
{
  food: "C",
  grade: ["1"]
},]

var display = document.getElementById("table-body");

var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = test[0]["food"]
cell2.innerHTML = test[0]["grade"]
```

```
For example:
Food || Grade
---------------
A       || 1
        || 2
        || 3
        || 5
---------------
B.     || 1
       || 2
---------------
C.     || 1
```

However, I'm only able to have them all listed in one cell i.e. (1,2,3,5). Any ideas on how to replicate the table above?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops to add rows for each task. Use the `rowspan` attribute in the first column to make it fill expand to all the rows for that device's tasks.

```
test.forEach(t => {
    t.tasks.forEach((task, i) => {
        let newRow = display.insertRow();
        if (i == 0) {
            let firstCell = newRow.insertCell();
            firstCell.innerText = t.device;
            firstCell.setAttribute('rowspan', t.tasks.length;
        }
        newRow.insertCell().innerText = task;
    });
});
```